# Why is it that I am getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sequence')'?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
 const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
 const arr = [];
 const input = document.getElementById('answer').value;

function displaySeq() {
        var i = 0;
        while (arr.length < 21) {
          arr[i] = {
              sequence: [],
              answer,
              guess: []
          };
          i++;

          for (j=0; j < 7; j++) {
              arr[i].sequence[0] = rndInt;
              arr[i].sequence.push(rndInt + j)
          }
       }  
        console.log(arr);
    }
```

I know that this error means that the variable does not have a value but I'm not sure what to do to resolve.

Another unrelated Question would be that my goal is that with every iteration a new random integer is the first element of each array. Right now it's the same random integer for each array. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: you are increasing the value of `i` before using it.
So it means if pushed an item at i=0 but you in next for loop you are trying to get i=1.

Simple way to fix this is by moving i++, after for loop. like

`

          for (var j=0; j < 7; j++) {
              arr[i].sequence[0] = rndInt;
              arr[i].sequence.push(rndInt + j);
          };
          i++;`

Also, you need to add var/let in for loop

Comment: `answer` appears to be undefined when you add the new item to the array. I would expect that to throw, because you can't use ES6 property shorthand with undefined vars.

Comment: this codesandbox might help you
https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-snowflake-325fwk?file=/src/index.js

you do have `answer` as undefined so I had assumed you are trying to use value of `input`

Comment: `rndInt` gets its value once, before the function is even defined. If you want it to return a new random value every time, move the declaration into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `arr[0]` when it is empty. So, first, you will have to push to the array and then call `arr[0]`.

Also, you are incrementing `i` and then pushing into the array. So, initially, you are accessing `arr[1]` before defining `arr[0]`.

Try this instead:

```
function displaySeq() {
     var i = 0;
     while (arr.length < 21) {
         arr.push({
             sequence: [],
             answer,
             guess: []
         });
         for (j=0; j < 7; j++) {
             arr[i].sequence[0] = rndInt;
             arr[i].sequence.push(rndInt + j)
         }
         i++;
     }  
     console.log(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Observation :** You are incrementing `i` after creating the array object and trying to access the array object at `i` index.

In simple way, you are trying to access `arr[i+1]` as at there is only one element in `arr` at this point of time.

**Resolution :** Increment the index `i++` after completion of `for` loop.

**Demo :**

```js
const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
const arr = [];

function displaySeq() {
  var i = 0;
  while (arr.length < 21) {
    arr[i] = {
      sequence: [],
      answer: [],
      guess: []
    };

    for (j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
      arr[i].sequence[0] = rndInt;
      arr[i].sequence.push(rndInt + j)
    } 
    
    i++;
  }  
  console.log(arr);
}

displaySeq();
```